# Line Chart Report with 2 Different Scales?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, graph, reportviewer

I have a line chart with two lines in it.  Sometimes the values between them differ by a hundred or more.  That leaves the bottom line looking very flat.  I want both of these to remain on the same graph but is there a way to have a different scale for each line?

I was told that it is possible to have one (scale) on the left and one on the right, but I have googled and googled and have not found anything useful.

So any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: After searching and searching I finally found a post on the MSDN forms from a Microsoft Moderator saying " It is currently not supported. This applies to RS 2000 and RS 2005. Adding this feature in RS charts natively is under consideration for a future release"

This was posted in 2006 so maybe there has been an update, anyone know?

Comment: The MSDN post referenced seems to be this one http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/00369845-b07d-4ad8-ba9a-6afe51c760bd/is-it-possible-to-have-secondary-axis-in-a-line-chart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the properties for the chart series change the ValueAxisName to Secondary

OR

1. Right-click on the chart series
2. Goto Series Properties
3. Goto Axes and Chart Areas
4. Change the value Axis to Secondary

Comment: What reporting service is this for?  I don't see either of these values.  I probably should have made it more clear in that this is in a Microsoft Local Report (.rdlc)

Comment: Ok, I was using VS 2008 with a little more research I found that this was not supported.  Upgraded to VS 2010 and your directions worked perfectly.  Thanks!