# How to add secondary Y- axis in RDLC chart in VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc

Is there any way to add a **secondary Y-axis** to a **RDLC line chart** in Visual Studio 2010. I read in many articles that it is possible, but none of the articles mentioned on how to do it.

Comment: Was looking for the same thing today came accross this, hope it helps... http://stackoverflow.com/a/3210409/1584672

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But It just changes the axis position right?, what i need is to add two Y-axis in one chart.